# NullReferenceException on dll

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code I get the error on:

```
Imports ADFactory

Public Class Salary
    Inherits Salary_Datalayer
    Protected _AD As New ADFactory.ADFactory

    Protected Sub Page_Load(...)Handles Me.Load
        _user = "username"
        sDealer = _AD.GetUserCompany(_user)
```

It states that `Protected _AD As New ADFactory.ADFactory` is the line throwing the exception.  I've looked online and read and changed it several times, declared 'New', am I missing something simple?

Comment: What is full error message and the stack trace of the exception? It seems possible that the error is comming from ADFactory and not your code. Is ADFactory part of your solution?

Comment: ADFactory is a reference to the project. It was written in C#, but I don't believe that matters. I've used the same dll in another C# solution coded: ADFactory.ADFactory _AD = New ADFactory.ADFactory()  And it worked just fine.

Comment: Firstly the full details of the exception should tell you exactly where the error is occurring, so that is worth providing. However, given you can't see any obvious reasons for a difference, start SysInternal's ProcessMonitor and compare the trace of the working project to the failing project.

Answer (score 0):

PatFromCanada was correct, my ADFactory was the problem.  I didn't properly initialize a connection string within the reference, thus always throwing a nullexception, which apparently, I run into quite often in my questions.  Thanks PatFromCanada!

Comment: How do I give PatFromCanada credit for answering my question?

Comment: Ask them to publish comment as an answer and accept/upvote that.

Comment: other than saying "thanks, Pat!" you cna't unless he adds an answer.